# How do I remove subdivision loops?

Tags: selection-tools

I am trying to manipulate a cube into a car; and I was able to make edge loops by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. However, when I am trying to make a wheel well, I want to make new subdivision loops to do that; yet the old ones are getting in they way.

How do I remove subdivision loops so that I can manipulate my object without old loops effecting the new ones?

Or basically, the opposite of what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can select them with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> to keep the existing selection), and then delete them with <kbd>Delete</kbd> *> Edge loops*, or <kbd>Delete</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> if you want to take advantage of menu hotkeys.

[image]

If you have many loops which you want to select, but don't want to click on each one, you can use *Multi select loops*, either from *3D view > Header > Select > Edge loops*, or <kbd>Space</kbd>*> Multi select loops*.

Comment: When I deleted the edge loop, it ended up changing the form of the object; that isn't what I want. I simply want to remove just the loop without changing the form of the object.

Comment: @user3423509 The topology defines the shape of the object. If you change the topology, you are liable to change the shape too.

Comment: Hrmm... Well this is the project I am working on: http://imgur.com/C4FFP1y 

I am trying to insert a wheel well into the front of the car. Now (this may be a bit hard to follow, but bare with me.) I want to insert the wheel well a bit underneath the hood (which is the left of the image. It may not be obvious considering my "skill level"), but the other cuts are making that quite a problem. How would I best remedy this issue?

Comment: @user3423509 are you asking a different question? if so, please ask it separately. If you're expanding on the original question please edit it with the new information.

Answer (score 0):

Select the edge and then in the left hand tool bar under 'delete' click the sub menu 'disolve' to remove selected edges.

Comment: This should be used with caution, though, as dissolving edges that are not unnecessary you damage the geometry.