# Join different Faces of one Mesh

Tags: modeling

How can i join different Faces, to texturize them better?

Example:
[image]

Comment: Can i Join for example 32 Of that faces into one?

Comment: Okay, that made it a bit easier, now can i joind quads, too?

Comment: Do not use a single N-Gon (polygon with more than 4 faces) for texturing, it will not make your life any easier, trust me.

Comment: @SimonDülpers There are various ways of remove extra geometry, e.g. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14308/how-do-i-remove-subdivision-loops and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/is-there-an-unsubdivide-function-in-blender